# What does NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL mean?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing a AJAX request using Angular 1.5.9. The code looks like this:

```
$http.get('localhost:8080/app/users').then(function(resp) { ... });
```

Why do I get this error?

"NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL" (...)
stack: "createHttpBackend/<@http://localhost:8080/app/libraries/angular.js:12115:5 ..."

The url exists and can be accessed from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually browsing `localhost:8080/app/users` makes the browser prefix it with `http://` which is missing here. That is why the error goes "unknown protocol".

The url has to be `http://localhost:8080/...`